# ruby on rails におけるモデル（DB）設計について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
以下のようなデータ構造を考えた場合、Position の親子関係(has_many,belongs_to等)はとる必要があるのかを教えていただきたくお願いいたします。
わからないのは Position は Home からも Road からも参照されるため、取り扱いの方法がわかりません。

- Home
  家情報
  Homeは１つのPositionをもってる
- Road
  道情報
  Roadは複数のPositionをもってる。Positionを繋ぐと道になるイメージ
- Postion
  座標情報
  Positionはx、y座標をもってる
  １個のPosition情報はHomeからもRoadからも参照される場合がある

お聞きしたい内容はおおよそ以下の3点です。
(1) Positionは「誰とも親子関係をむすばない」で正しいでしょうか？

(2) Positionは誰とも親子関係をむすばないとした場合、Homeのテーブルはposition_idフィールドを１つ持ち、Positionが必要な時にposition_idで検索するべきなんでしょうか？

(3) RoadはPositionを複数もっているため中間結合テーブルRoadPositionsを作成して対応するべきなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関連は必ずしも双方向に設定する必要はありません。「親子関係」という言葉に引きずられて余計な制約を想像されてるような気がします。

> (1) Positionは「誰とも親子関係をむすばない」で正しいでしょうか？

`Position`から`Home`や`Road`を引っ張ってくる必要が無ければ、`Position`からの関連を設定する必要はありません。

> (2) Positionは誰とも親子関係をむすばないとした場合、Homeのテーブルはposition_idフィールドを１つ持ち、Positionが必要な時にposition_idで検索するべきなんでしょうか？

`Home`に`position_id`を持たせるのはそれでよいとして、`belongs_to :position`として関連を設定すれば良いでしょう

> (3) RoadはPositionを複数もっているため中間結合テーブルRoadPositionsを作成して対応するべきなんでしょうか？

```
      a
      |
  b---c---d
      |
      e
```

a～eがそれぞれの`Position`のレコードで、「a-c-e」とか「b-c-d」で`Road`を表現するということだと思いますが、`Road`は単に複数の`Position`を持っているというだけでなく、「a-c-e」(a-e-cではなく）というつながりも表現する必要があると思います。

単純に多対多の関連で済ませて中間テーブルにソート順みたいなものを持たせるので十分なのか、別の表現方法やデータ構造で保存した方がいいのかはデータ量とか利用方法によって変わってきます。グラフについてのアルゴリズムの知識が必要です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご回答していただいた内容でほぼ全ての疑問が解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

> - Home
>     家情報
>     Homeは１つのPositionをもってる
> - Road
>     道情報
>     Roadは複数のPositionをもってる。Positionを繋ぐと道になるイメージ
> - Postion
>     座標情報
>     Positionはx、y座標をもってる
>     １個のPosition情報はHomeからもRoadからも参照される場合がある

何が何を持っているのか、ここまでまとまってるのでしたら、そのまま以下のように設定すれば良いかと思います。

- Home

  ```
  has_one :position
  ```
- Road

  ```
  has_many :positions
  ```
- Position

  ```
  belongs_to :home
  belongs_to :road
  ```

テーブルとしては、positions テーブルに home_id と road_id を持たせる感じです。
homes や roads テーブルには position_id は不要です。

(1)〜(3) のご質問に対する回答としては、

(1) 結べば良いと思います
(2) 結ぶので回答を省略します
(3) positions の複数のレコードの road_id が同じ値になるだけです。中間テーブルは不要と思います。

となります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もう一点質問させてください。Positionの条件が、１個のPosition情報は複数のHomeからも複数のRoadからも参照される場合があるはどのように設計するべきでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Home を `has_many :positions` とするだけだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。